# Using Non-Local Data/Media Files with a C++ Application (gtkmm)

Tags: c++, autotools, automake, gtkmm

I'm beginning development on an acoustic spectrum analysis tool (inspired by [spek](http://spek-project.org)) written in C++ with gtkmm (C++ bindings for the GTK+ GUI toolkit). I would imagine that I should know how to do this by now, however...

My directory structure is a-la-GNOME, e.g `src/`, `data/`, `po/`, `man/`. The specific situation that presented the need for my inquiry is the use of a GTK UI Manager that will be located in `data/ui`. For this specific situation, I want to be able to load the user-interface from this file in an install-independent manner (e.g. loading of the file does not depend on a `make install`; the executable may be run [and load the UI file] either from `src/` after running `make` [thus compiling the sources into the selfsame exectuable] or from its install prefix). How would I refer to the UI file in my source code (keeping in mind that the loading of the file is not performed by creating a file object (`fopen(...)`) but rather by passing a file location as a string argument to `(UIManager).add_ui_from_file(...)`)?

In addition to this particular situation of a UI file, how would I do similar references to files (i.e. databases, INI files, XML schemas) by using the autotools build process? Is there a piece of relevant Automake code to quickly set up a project to use this type of directory structure?

Answer (score 1):

simply try to use both files (with the un-installed taking precedence):

```
if(!(UIManager).add_ui_from_file(../data/ui/mygui))
   (UIManager).add_ui_from_file(/incalled/location/mygui)
```

Comment: You should not be hard-coding file locations in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In Glom, I created a helper function that tries both locations, with both locations being defined in the Makefile.am (this is simpler if you have only one Makefile.am, by using non-recursive automake, which is simpler anyway):
http://git.gnome.org/browse/glom/tree/glom/glade_utils.h#n38